# How does a graphical front-end control a daemon?

Tags: gui, programming, services

I'm developing a file sync daemon on Ubuntu as a hobby project, and I'm thinking I might want to develop a graphical front-end at some point which will let me control it. How can a GUI control and communicate with a daemon program? What methods are available / recommended?

In this particular case, I'm using C++, but a general answer applicable to any language would also be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. Communicate using D-Bus which is very popular this days.
2. Just change a configuration file and signal your daemon to reload it (`SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` and `SIGHUP` have exactly this purpose).
3. Write your own protocol with something like Thrift or Protocol Buffers.
4. Use a low level IPC mechanism.

In your place I would go with D-Bus

Comment: Thanks! If I decide to go with D-Bus, is there any reference I can look at to get started?

Comment: Check [dbus official site](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/#index4h1)